# How can I integrate a SharePoint document folder in a separate ASP.NET web site?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint

How can I show/embed a document folder from a SharePoint site on a separate intranet asp.net web app to allow users to download the documents and browse into subfolders? We do not want to allow any check-out or edits from the ASP site.

Back Story:
My company has a SharePoint set up to house Policies and Procedures for employees to use, and I have set up an ASP web forms site to house some simple tools that are commonly used & updated.

The issue that we are running into is that keeping the ASP app updated as the SharePoint changes becomes tedious as there are hundreds of documents that are updated quarterly.

The ideal solution would have a page on the ASP app, lets call "Documents" and when an user visits that, they are shown a list or list tree of documents & subfolders that are available for download from a specified "published" documents folder on SharePoint, or an embedded view of that folder from the SharePoint.

Comment: Have you considered using an iframe?

Comment: First, Thank you for catching the title typo. Second, I have not explored this option, but I will.

Comment: The other option is to use one of the SharePoint APIs to create your own user interface to the library.